# Change the text of an anchor link depending the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery or JavaScript is it possible to change/add to the text of an anchor link depending on what page the user is on.

So I would like this:

```
<a href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
```

To change to the following if the user is not on the homepage:

```
<a href="/homepage/#section-2">Section 2</a>
```

Comment: by "page" do you mean "section" within the same page?

Comment: Could you not always use `/homepage/#section-2`? What would the disadvantage of just doing that be?

Comment: What have you tried and What is not working ? How do you want apply the condition ? Considering the page URL ?

Comment: Do you mean changing the value of the html code or the URL?

Comment: So I have a homepage with lots of different sections that the user can jump to and there are also different pages that are not on the homepage. If the user goes to a different page then I need to be able to jump back to a section on the homepage. In the menu it's always #section-1 and when clicked it just adds that to the end of a page url instead of going back to the homepage/#section-1 
Hopefully that makes some sense?

Comment: Sorry I meant change the html not URL

Comment: I'm using fullpagescroll.js and it doesn't seem to work if I use /homepage/#section-2 on the homepage.

Comment: Odd when I add the following html "/homepage/#section-2" in the url it removes the slash so it reads /homepage#section-2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `href` using the [function `attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The next code will change the `href`:

```
var anchor = $("a").attr("href");
$("a").attr("href", "homepage/" + anchor );
```

And if you want conditions depending of the anchor of your URL, you can do something with this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var idx = url.indexOf("#");
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";
```

And then:

```
if(hash === "#whatever"){
    var anchor = $("a").attr("href");
    $("a").attr("href", "homepage/" + anchor );
}
```

If there is no anchor you will have `hash = ""`, so you can assume `hash === ""` is the homepage

Comment: Selector seems wrong! Where are the conditions to take the action ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I missunderstood the question, but I think I fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the [base url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.yoursite.com/homepage/">
</head>
```